# 1 Pager Timeline Navigation

Tags: jquery, css

Hi all i have been trying to find a solution to create something like the image below. it is like the timeline navigation when u click it will go to anywhere on the page or when u scroll the page down it will highlight which area has been past.

here is the sample site i found http://aquatilis.tv/ frm this site i only manage to find the css do the job but not sure which part of the jquery have to do with it also ...

if you all have any other plug in already been found can be use please share here

[image: Look at the red arrow]

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: Andrew & Jayababu i have tried prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr but still not really like this site i looking for